# Shouldn't we all migrate to Lambda@Edge from API-Gateway + Lambda stack for API serving?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Serving APIs from `Lambda@Edge` offers more latency benefit than serving APIs from `API-Gateway + Lambda` stack, if my understanding is correct.

Plus, cost of API-Gateway ($3.5/million call) + Lambda ($0.2/million call) == $3.7 / million call seems to be more expensive than `Lambda@Edge` ($0.6 / million call).

If both of the above observations are true, shouldn't we all migrate our API-Gateway + Lambda (for those who use this stack) to lambda@edge stack?

Comment: CloudFront costs you $1/million so total price with Lambda@edge would be $1.6/million so Api Gateway can be cheaper if you use HTTP API.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda@Edge is primarily event driven for requests, yes the latency is reduced but it is designed to be used with an origin. Even if you have the Lambda@Edge function your CloudFront distribution would still need to reach out to the origin.

When the origin is an API Gateway (with or without a Lambda) there are so many benefits come with it such as:

- Built in support for OpenAPI spec
- Built in routing
- Support for canary deployments
- Authentication and authorization built in, with support for throttling per API user
- Built in support for model schema validation
- Support to manage your API as Infrastructure as Code: [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ApiGateway.html), [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_rest_api.html), [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html)
- Each request can be developed separately, you can only have 1 Lambda@Edge function per event so you might see collisions in a team (not to mention very large functions).

If this was all needed to be done by Lambda@Edge then you would need to design, develop and maintain these features.

The price you refer to is for REST API, bare in mind there 3 kinds of API the cheapest is HTTP API which costs `$1.00` per million requests.

Answer (score 2):

`Lambda@Edge` has [many limitations](http://Requirements%20and%20Restrictions%20on%20Lambda%20Functions) as compared to regular lambda. For examples:

- its only for node.js and python,
- no lambda layers!
- no AWS X-Ray!
- max timeout 30 seconds,
- and many more.

Thus, it would be difficult in many cases to migrate to `Lambda@Edge` and to give up all these benefits of regular lambda.

Comment: Do you know how to do the reverse migration i.e. from lambda@edge to regular lambda? Do you know of a guide/doc that explains the necessary steps? I'm still learning my way around aws to bear with me pls.